# Setting TableViewCell Label colour on row selection Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a TableView, and the table is populated from an array. The cell is of type TableViewCell.xib. I want to change the colour of the label in the cell.

Here's my TableViewController

```
struct cell_data {
    let label1: String!
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let cellDataArray = [cell_data]([cell_data(label1: "This text is for label 1")])

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellDataArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! TableViewCell

        cell.label_1.text = cellDataArray[indexPath.row].label1
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:5, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: cell.frame.size.height - 7))
        whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3

        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
        cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)


    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)


    }
}
```

What I want to do be able to do is change the colour of the label of the cell when I select a row **without affecting the UIView inside the cell.** That is, once I change the height of the UIView when I select a row, I  have tried reloading but reloading the cell set the UIView's height to the original setting.

And once I have set the label's colour, I want to set it back to it's original colour when I deselect the row.

I hope I made it clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you change the label to the color you want in tableView:didSelectRowAt: and reset it in tableView:didDeselectRowAt: ?

Comment: @ubiAle No. When I change the label in didSelectRowAt, I would need to reload the row, meaning it would also reload the UIView and I would lose all changes made to it when I selected.

Comment: why do you need to reload the row?

Comment: @ubiAle How else can I update the label itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reloading the cell to update the label's color. You can try by overriding method in your TableViewCell with the following code:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
 super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
 if (selected) {
   //Change your label color for selected state
 } else {
   //Change your label color for unselected state
 }
}
```

Comment: OP also wants to increase the height of a view inside the cell. For that he **will** have to reload the cell!

Comment: It's something like expandable cell? 
If it's that case, he can reload cell to increase the height of the inner view and cell height itself. By saving selectedIndexPath and try to select that cell programmatically after cell is reloaded.

Comment: @Rikh Forgot to mention that the height DOES update with my current code without reloading due to `tableView.updateBegin`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 

   {
      let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! customTableViewCell // name of your custom cell class
      cell.label_1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()//give your selection color

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt    indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as yourCell
    cell.yourlable.textcolor = yourColor;

}
```